# I need to convert this string to datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

String:

```
'01/04/2019 01:50:31.230000000'
```

Expected result:

```
01/04/2019 01:50:31.230
```

as a `DATETIME`.

Query used:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/04/2019 01:50:31.230000000', 113)
```

Comment: `datetime` values do not have a format.  They are stored in an internal format.

Comment: You want style `103`. Check the documentation on `CONVERT` for the list of style codes.

Answer (score 3):

Converting that string, which is in the [103 format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql), would work if it didn't have the last 6 zero's.
So a `SUBSTRING` or `LEFT` could be used to keep only 23 characters.
And then convert it to a DATETIME.

But that string, can be converted just fine to a DATETIME2.
Since a DATETIME2 is more accurate.
And a DATETIME2 can be simply casted or converted to a DATETIME.

Note that DATETIME isn't stored with a format in the table.
The way it's displayed is a setting.

However, you can [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) a DATETIME back to a string in the [specific format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) you need. (starting with SQL Server 2012)

Example snippet:

```
select 
col as col_input_string,
CAST(CONVERT(datetime2, col, 103) AS datetime) as col_as_datetime,
FORMAT(CONVERT(datetime2, col, 103), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff') as col_as_formatted_string
from (values 
 ('01/04/2019 01:50:31.230000000')
,('31/12/2018 13:33:44.123456789')
) q(col);
```

Result:

```
col_input_string                col_as_datetime             col_as_formatted_string
01/04/2019 01:50:31.230000000   2019-04-01 01:50:31.230     01/04/2019 01:50:31.230
31/12/2018 13:33:44.123456789   2018-12-31 13:33:44.123     31/12/2018 13:33:44.123
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you want is:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,LEFT('01/04/2019 01:50:31.230000000',23),103);
```

You need to use `LEFT` as `datetime` is only accurate to 1/300 of a second; thus you need to trim off the accuracy that can't be used.

Comment: You could also simply use datetime2  ...  CONVERT(DATETIME2, '01/04/2019 01:50:31.230000000',103)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
declare @vardate varchar(50) = '01/04/2019 01:50:31.230000000'
declare @date datetime =convert(date, left(@vardate,23), 103)
declare @time time = convert(time, substring(@vardate,12,12), 14)

select DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, @time, @date), CAST(@time AS DATETIME)) AS Result
```

if that does not work check different convert formats.

Comment: `date` doesn't have a time portion; this won't give the result the OP wants.

Comment: Have you tested that? Why not just use `datetime`..?

Comment: i tried but i was not able to find a convert format that fits "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.mmm"